# PHP force download of Amazon S3 link

Tags: php, amazon-s3, download

I have the following code

```
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Type: audio/mp3');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $arrResults['audioLink'] . ".mp3");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        $strLink = 'http://ag-org.s3.amazonaws.com/members/tele_classes/' . $arrResults['audioLink'];

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($strLink);
```

However when the download link is clicked that executes this code it always returns a 0 byte file. All files are set to public in the bucket.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have fopen wrappers enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `.mp3` extension really not part of the filename as it's stored on S3?

You're appending `.mp3` to the filename in the Content-Disposition header, but not the URL you're passing to `readfile`.

Comment: D'oh, I hate it when I do that